# Drawing circles with radius that is equal to finger path

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to create an app where the user places one finger on the screen and a circle is drawn on the screen. The center of the circle is placed where the user touched the screen. The user moves their finger to increase the radius of the circle. While the user is moving their finger the circle is drawn, with the edge of the circle under the user's finger.

Right now my code creates circles of a random radius with a center at the place where the user touched the screen. I need help with figuring out how to make a radius of a circle to be depended on the user's finger path.

So I have a class CircleView: UIView which is a cocoa touch class. It has the following functions in it:

```swift
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Get the Graphics Context
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

        // Set the circle outerline-width
        context.setLineWidth(5.0);

        // Set the circle outerline-colour
        UIColor.green.set()

        // Create Circle
        let center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)
        let radius = (frame.size.width - 10)/2
        context.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)

        // Draw
        context.strokePath()
        }
```

My class ViewController: UIViewController has following functions right now:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            // Set the Center of the Circle
            // 1
            let circleCenter = touch.location(in: view)

            // Set a random Circle Radius
            // 2
            let circleWidth = CGFloat(25 + (arc4random() % 50))
            let circleHeight = circleWidth

            // Create a new CircleView
            // 3
            let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: circleCenter.x, y: circleCenter.y, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
            view.addSubview(circleView)
        }
    }
```

I would like to create circles, not of a random radius but of a radius that the user can set by dragging his finger. In the future, I will also like to implement deleting and moving modes for my app. The moving mode will let the user drag circles around the screen.

Comment: Just use the `touchesMoved` method. Store the first touch in `touchesBegan` and get the distance between the first touch and the current touch. That would be the radius. Draw the circle in `touchesEnded`

Answer (score 0):

well , agree with @Marina comment. only u have to add check for users finger direction as touch will return CGPoint(x:,y:).

```
let initialRadius = 0
var currentRadius = 10


func touchBegan(...){ 
initialRadius = currentRadius

}
func touchMoves(...) {

Y = touch(in view).Y
X = touch(in view).x

if direction == vertical {
     currentdistance = substract point Y from first touch (center.Y)
(after that you have to abs() current distance for negative value)
  currentRadius =  abs(currentdistance)

} else if direction == horizontal {  currentdistance = substract point X from first touch  (center.X)
(after that you have to abs() current distance for negative value)
currentRadius =  abs(currentdistance)
} else {

either X or Y

}
}

func touchEnded(...){

drawcircle(radius)
```